# Does the latest version of QTP have something similar to Selenium Grid?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, qtp, browser-automation

Does anyone know whether QTP supports parallel test execution on multiple browsers now? I am looking for something similar to Selenium Grid.

Comment: I guess QTP always used to have master slave kind of mechanism to parallelize tests. Though not sure how many browsers they support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTP does not support parallel runs on different browsers, you can run the same test on different browsers by defining the browser in the data table and then iterate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel execution can be achieved by integration with Quality Center, in which case you can set up a test set to execute against a number of different hosts. Alternatively, you can build your own, or utilize another system, such as your build farm, to dole out QTP jobs.

Comment: This enables you to run several QTP tests in parallel on *different* machines. It won't allow you to run tests in parallel on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of both existing answers, you can create Test Configurations within QC to specify different data table values for a single test.

When I require testing on multiple browsers, I create two or more configurations which specify the browser for that run.

- Test A IE
- Test A Chrome
- Test A Firefox

If you have multiple hosts, you can then run the test in parallel on each host.  If not, you are limited to running them consecutively on one host, which in practice would function similar to the data table iterations Motti suggested.

Setting it up this way does allow for an easy transition to parallel testing should you expand the number of hosts available to you.